# $animate.on callback never entering 'close' phase

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css-animations, ng-animate

In this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9WmxI26p6oLLTsJRyvq4?p=preview) I have created some simple animations on a ng-repeat.

I want to do stuff when the enter and leave animation are finished.

It works fine with enter:

```
$animate.on('enter', element, function(element, phase){
  if(phase === 'close'){
     //do stuff
  }
});
```

this callback is called twice, once with `phase === 'start'` and once with `phase === 'close'`

howerver if I change `'enter'` to `'leave'` the callback is only called once, with `phase === 'start'`

Check the plunker console.logs to see this behavior.

Is there anything wrong with my jsCode/html/css that could be the reason or am I not thinking correctly in doing stuff when animations are finished?

Comment: This is apparently a known issue. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6049. If you inspect the ticket there are a few 'work arounds' people have used. Maybe one of those will work for you.

Comment: I'll check that out. Thanks!